# Error when pushing forked Laravel package to Heroku

Tags: git, laravel, heroku

I'm experiencing an issue with a Laravel package that I forked from Bitbucket. I created a new repo on Git and pushed this modified version of the package; everything works fine locally but, when I push the code to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
remote : [RunTimeException]

remote : Failedto execute git clone --no-checkout 'git@github.com:myvendor/mypackage && cd 'tmp/build/...' && git remote add composer 'git@git....'
```

Here's my `composer.json` from my main Laravel project:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/myvendor/mypackage.git"
    }
  ],
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the git repo public?

Comment: yes this repo is public